# How can I make react's useEffect to stop rerender in an infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

So I am working on a small personal project that is a todo app basically, but with a backend with express and mongo. I use `useEffect()` to make an axios get request to the `/all-todos` endpoint that returns all of my todos. Then inside of `useEffect()`'s dependency array I specify the todos array as dependency, meaning that I want the `useEffect()` to cause a rerender anytime the tasks array gets modified in any way. Take a look at this:

```
export default function () {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))._id;

    useEffect(() => {
        function populateTodos () {
            axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/all-todos/${currentUser}`)
                .then(res => setTodos(res.data))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }

        populateTodos();
    }, [todos]);

    console.log(todos);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

So I placed that `console.log()` there to give me a proof that the component gets rerendered, and the problem is that the `console.log()` gets printed to the console forever, until the browser gets slower and slower.
How can I make it so that the `useEffect()` gets triggered obly when todos gets changed?

Comment: Remove todos from your useEffect dependency, add setTodos instead.

Comment: It is doing an infinite loop because the state you are setting inside useEffect is the same one on the dependencies list as well. So whenever your state changes, the useEffect will run again.

Answer (score 1):

You should execute the hook only if `currentUser` changes:

```
export default function () {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))._id;

    useEffect(() => {
        function populateTodos () {
            axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/all-todos/${currentUser}`)
                .then(res => setTodos(res.data))
                .catch(err => setError(err));
        }

        populateTodos();
    }, [currentUser]);

    console.log(todos);

    if (error) return (
        <div className="App">
            There was an error fetching resources: {JSON.stringify(error)}
        </div>
    )

    return (
        <div className="App">
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't rerender forever like before but also doesn't rerender when the state(todos) changes.

Comment: Is the response successfull? If not, it wont render again

Comment: Could you expand on that a bit?

Comment: On unsuccesfull response, you are just looging the error. Only different states or different props trigger a new render.

Comment: I see now what you mean. I think I will have to make it happen from other components, like the component where I create anew todo. I will look into that. Thank you.

Comment: @TarasiCristiAndrei I updated the question so you can see how to manage fetch errors